# Problems with assertions, specifically the negative lookahead assertion 'x(?!y)'

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, assertion

So I have been practicing and reading about assertions, and ran into this problem:

```
const text14 = "123 456 7890";
const pattern12 = /\d+(?!0)/g;

let matches12 = text14.match(pattern12);
console.log(matches12);
```

the output is supposed to be ['123', '456']
Yet it isn't.
its ['123', '456', '7890']

After tinkering with it a bit I realized that when I put a space on the assertion as well as on the string itself, it removed, yet only the 9.

```
const text14 = "123 456 789 0";
const pattern12 = /\d+(?! 0)/g;

let matches12 = text14.match(pattern12);
console.log(matches12);
```

Ouput:

```
['123', '456', '78', '0']
```

This made me believe that there is a different way in which assertion works with numbers.
The desired outcome I've been trying to get is to turn the original "123 456 7890" into ['123', '456'] using the negative lookahead assertion: 'x(?!y)'.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `/\d+(?!0)/g` will match all substrings that:

- begin with a sequence of digits (as many as possible, at least one)
- are not followed by a 0

The problem is that 0 is itself a digit. The regex keeps accepting digits including zeroes until it encounters a character that isn't a digit, and only then does it check that the character after that is not a zero. So the negative lookahead never comes into play.

You might be tempted to simply use negative lookbehind instead, like so:

```
"123 456 7890".match(/\d+(?<!0)/g); // ["123", "456", "789"]
```

But in such a case the regular expression will simply stop before the zero instead, and not discard the entire sequence as you wished. Instead, you should first match a sequence of digits that ends in a nonzero digit, then make sure there isn't another digit after that.

```
"123 456 7890".match(/\d*[1-9](?!\d)/g); // ["123", "456"]
```

Keep in mind that the way you write a regular expression can affect its performance. I would not expect this one to be very efficient. A more naïve approach would be to simply accept any sequence of digits and then filter the results with JavaScript:

```
"123 456 7890"
    .match(/\d+/g)                  // ["123, 456", "7890"]
    .filter(s => s.at(-1) !== "0"); // ["123, 456"]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference in how the regular expression engine assertion treats digits or other characters.

Your digit match is too "greedy": the `\d+` is matching **all of the digits** (including 0) before it checks the negative lookahead `(?!0)`.

So it does something like this:

- Does `7890` match `\d+`? **yes**
- Is `7890` followed by `(?!0)`? **no** (because there are no remaining digits)
- Therefore `7890` is successfully matched.

You can try this out by going to: https://regex101.com/
Enter your regular expression and test strings, then choose the "Regex Debugger" from the left-hand sidebar menu (under "TOOLS").

[regular-expressions.info is another great resource](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with a really good explanation of lookahead and lookbehind assertions.

There are a couple of alternative patterns that might do what you want.

`\b[1-9]+(?!0)\b`

- exclude `0` from the digit match allows the negative lookahead will come into play
- adding word boundary `\b` checks at the start and end allows it will match whole groups (avoiding partial matches like `78`)
- however, this will never match any group that contains 0 (which may not be what you want)

Results:

```
"123 456 7890" -> [123, 456]
"123 456 789" -> [123, 456, 789]
"1023 456 789" -> [456, 789]
"000 1230 0456" -> []
```

`\b\d+(?<!0)\b`

- this uses a negative lookbehind assertion
- "match every group of digits that doesn't end with `0`"
- this allows 0 at the start or middle of the group

Results:

```
"123 456 7890" -> [123, 456]
"123 456 789" -> [123, 456, 789]
"1023 456 789" -> [1023, 456, 789]
"000 1230 0456" -> [0456]
```

Note that consistent browser/engine support for [negative lookbehind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Lookbehind_assertion) is only relatively new (at time of writing).

It's been available in Chrome since 2017-10, nodejs since 2018-03, Firefox since 2020-06, Safari since 2023-03.

Comment: The negative lookahead in `\b[1-9]+(?!0)\b` is pointless; if the string matches `\b` at that point it can't possibly match `0`. https://regex101.com/r/vmMRgI/1

Comment: Haha, I felt bad that we both posted long answer at the same time, but we had different approaches. `\b` is likely an excellent idea in this case, though indeed the lookahead is then unnecessary.

Comment: @Nick good point! I was so focussed on the lookahead I didn't think about what it really meant

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your pattern `\d+(?!0)` could be written as just `\d+` as it matches any digits 1 or more times.

The lookahead at the end will always be true as it just matched all digits.

---

For your example data, you don't need any lookarounds.

```
\b[1-9](?:\d*[1-9])?\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[1-9]` Match a digit 1-9
- `(?:\d*[1-9])?` Optionally match optional digits and a single digit 1-9
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l2ozWV/1)

```js
const text14 = "123 456 7890";
const pattern12 = /\b[1-9](?:\d*[1-9])?\b/g;
console.log(text14.match(pattern12));
```

You could make use of a lookbehind assertion if that is supported, but I would suggest to first use the word boundary before the assertion to prevent unnecessarily firing the lookbehind while backtracking if there is no match:

```
\b\d+\b(?<!0)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FIQqFx/1)